# GDB Hangs after “New Thread” on macOS

Tags: mac, gdb

I have built GDB from source on macOS 12.0 and codesigned it. However, every time I try to debug a program, I get this:

```
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x10000324f: file main.cpp, line 50.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /Users/tjcaul/Documents/C++/a.out 
[New Thread 0x2a03 of process 2389]
```

and then GDB hangs. I have been compiling C++ programs with g++. Here are some things I have tried:

1. Compile with -g option.
2. Compile with -ggdb option.
3. Compile with -ggdb3 option.
4. Run with `sudo`
5. Kill and re-run gdb repeatedly.
6. Try different binaries.
7. Disable SIP
8. Add more breakpoints.
9. `set startup-with-shell off` in `.gdbinit`

I do *not* get taskgated / Mach Port errors; only the New Thread message.

I realize that this is a near-duplicate of [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/377934/mysterious-gdb-hangs-after-clean-build), but I didn't see a working answer on that question.

For reference, here are my versions:

```
$ g++ --version
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin21.0.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

```
$ gdb --version
GNU gdb (GDB) 10.2
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot help, but I see the same issue, I suggest the OP check `log stream --predicate 'process = "taskgated" OR (process = "kernel" AND eventMessage CONTAINS "macOSTaskPolicy")' --info` from an admin account. I see messages like ` 0    taskgated: (Security) [com.apple.securityd:security_exception] MacOS error: -67062`, indicating errors related to signing (but I don't know how to solve the problem, maybe I need to sign the debuggee itself?)

Comment: Same here with g++-11 -ggdb3, signed gdb binary, and sudo on Darwin Kernel Version 21.1.0.  Alas.

Answer (score 0):

As usual, attention to detail was the issue. I saw that `g++ --version` reported `clang`, but I didn’t think about it enough. I had assumed that GDB was the problem, not my compiler. I’m not sure why Apple linked g++ to clang++, since that’s quite misleading. This little oversight made me spend 8 months writing C++ on my phone (vi on a 60-character wide display is not my ideal IDE).

What I did to get *real* g++:

1. Install gcc with Homebrew
2. Soft-link (`ln -s`) gcc-11 and g++-11 from `/usr/local/Cellar/` to `/usr/local/bin/`
3. `unhash` (at least in zsh) gcc and g++, or else `gcc` will continue to expand to `/usr/bin/clang`

GDB is working most of the time now.

Answer (score 0):

This hang hits gdb bug: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=24069

You can install gdb from this source with patch:

```
brew install --force --build-from-source domq/gdb/gdb  # a patched version based on 10.1
```

or you can

```
brew update
brew install gdb # use gdb 12.1
```

It works for me, and I found it from this link: https://gist.github.com/mike-myers-tob/9a6013124bad7ff074d3297db2c98247